# #define C++ keyword 'case' in switch case statements?

Tags: c++, macros

I am preparing for a coding competition where you get bonus points if your code is shorter. I was wondering if one could '#define' the 'case' keyword from switch case statements so that if I have to use switch case statements in the competition, I don't have to type 'case' keyword again and again in the switch statement.

Example Code Snippet :

```
             switch(input_string[0])
        {
            case '+':p = (a + b);t;
            case '-':p = (a - b);t;
            case '*':p = (a * b);t;
            case '/':p = (a / b);t;
            case '%':p = (a % b);t;
            case '^':p = pow(a,b);t;
        }
```

a,b and p are integers. When the character input_string[0] is '+', a and b are added and the sum is assigned to p.

IMPORTANT: The 't' in the above code snippet is the break statement. I have used '#define t break;' so that I don't have to write the break keyword multiple times. I was wondering if one could do the same with the 'case' keyword.

Could I define case as '#define c case' and use 'c' wherever I need to use 'case' in the switch case statements so that the resulting code snippet looks like this:

```
        switch(e[i])
        {
            c '+':p = (a + b);t;
            c '-':p = (a - b);t;
            c '*':p = (a * b);t;
            c '/':p = (a / b);t;
            c '%':p = (a % b);t;
            c '^':p = pow(a,b);t;
        }
```

I tried doing '#define c case' but I get the following error - "error: expected 'case' keyword before expression"

Comment: Just try it. But make sure that this is what the competition meant by “short code”. Unless it’s an obfuscation contest, this is on the contrary inviting negative points because it makes the code unreadable. Outside obfuscation competitions, “short code” is usually measured in terms of complexity and boilerplate, not in number of characters.

Comment: In the time it took you to write out this question you could have just tried it for yourself.

Comment: ITYM `#define c case`, not `#define case c`. It's a very bad idea though - e.g. any time you define a local variable called `c` then it will be converted to `case`, and hilarity will ensue.

Comment: How about `#define c(x,...) case x:__VA_ARGS__;break;`? Naturally, you can have a define for __VA_ARGS__ as well if you use it many times...

Comment: @0x5453 I have edited my post. I tried it, but I keep getting the error "error: expected 'case' keyword before expression"

Comment: I would encourage you to look deeper than just shortening words, there are undoubtedly other ways you could shorten the amount of characters in this code by improving the algorithm.  Or at the very least, you'd be starting an interesting discussion about how to do it.

Comment: @SrihariVignesh, it does compile.  See this: http://ideone.com/swqU9a

Comment: @BatCoder If I don't undefine it I keep getting the error "expected 'case' keyword before expression" with my compiler. I use this following command in my Mac to compile it - "g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.out"

WhiZTiM's answer solved my problem. Thank you for taking time to solve my problem.

Comment: what about the "c" in "switch", do you want this to get expanded into "switcaseh" ??

Comment: @BatCoder how does your code compile? Won't the 'c' in 'switch' also get replaced with 'case'?

Comment: @tobi303 somehow WhiZTiM's answer works even though the 'switch' statement appears after the '#define c case' statement. The 'c' in 'switch' isn't replaced by 'case' for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend not doing that. But if you do that, please undefine it **immediately**, else very bad things will happen anywhere `c` is seen, and in whatever context

```
    #define c case
    #define t break;
    switch(e[i])
    {
        c '+':p = (a + b);t;
        c '-':p = (a - b);t;
        c '*':p = (a * b);t;
        c '/':p = (a / b);t;
        c '%':p = (a % b);t;
    }
    #undef c
    #undef t
```

In this case, the processor is basically a token replacement facility that will run before actual compilation.

---

This is even shorter than your original code:

```
#define c case
#define t break
switch(e[i]){c'+':p=(a+b);t;c'-':p=(a-b);t;c'*':p=(a*b);t;c'/':p=(a/b);t;c'%':p=(a % b);t;c'^':p=pow(a,b);}
#undef c
#undef t
```

As you can see, *shorter* is a very bad idea, except in code obfuscation challenges

Comment: I am sorry, I used "#define c case" only in the original code. I switched it in the question by mistake. I keep getting the error "error: expected 'case' keyword before expression" no matter what. Even if I delete the whitespace between 'c' and '+'

Comment: Yes your solution worked beautifully. I immediately undefined it after using it and the error disappeared. Thank You.

Comment: @SrihariVignesh, that is because, when you defined such macro, everywhere the preprocessor sees the token `c`, it replaces it with `case`... this will happen until the point where that macro is `undef`ined, or until the end of the translation unit.

Comment: in your solution, the word 'switch' appears after the #define statement, but still it compiles correctly. Won't the 'c' in 'switch' also get replaced by 'case'?

Comment: @SrihariVignesh, no it wouldn't. It replaces [tokens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yx2xe3h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). `switch` is a token and cannot be considered the same as `c`. But in something like: `c = 343+b` ...here `c` is a token.. The preprocessor thinks of tokens as any contiguous sequence of alphanumeric characters, that excludes newlines, punctuation, blanks, etc

Comment: Ah I see. Will have to exercise caution when using this thing then.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, yes. You could replace any C++ keyword with a macro if you wanted.

You need to be careful not to clash with any existing identifiers however. Remember that if you use a `c` token anywhere else that it will also become "case" when the preprocessor runs.

P.S. if code shortness is quantified by literally the fewest number of characters in your program, get rid of that pesky whitespace.

Comment: I already tried using it, but I keep getting the error "error: expected 'case' keyword before expression"

Comment: fortunately the editor they use doesn't count whitespaces :)

Comment: @SrihariVignesh - Sounds like your macro isn't defined correctly then. If you are defining the macro as you did in your question, you need to swap the values round: `#define c case`.

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you want you need to do `#define c case` instead. What you try to do is to replace all `c`s with `case` and not replace all `case`s with `c`. That is:

```
#define c case

switch(e[i])
    {
        c '+':p = (a + b);t;
        c '-':p = (a - b);t;
        c '*':p = (a * b);t;
        c '/':p = (a / b);t;
        c '%':p = (a % b);t;
        c '^':p = pow(a,b);t;
    }
```